# overflow navigation bar in flutter application using google_nav_bar library

Tags: flutter

In my bottom navigation bar for my time management app i am having overflow problem.

```
bottomNavigationBar: GNav(
        tabActiveBorder: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
        tabBorderRadius: 55,
        tabBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(105, 107, 105, 105),
        gap: 5,
        textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
        onTabChange: (index) {},
        tabs: const [
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.schedule,
            text: "Clock",
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.language,
            text: "World",
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.alarm,
            text: "Alarm",
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.timer,
            text: "Timer",
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: Icons.calendar_month_outlined,
            text: "To Do",
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

here is my code for bottom navigation bar.

I tried wrapping the gnav widget in expanded widget but it causes the navigation bar to disappear all together. I am not that sound in flutter and this is my first official project that i am doing myself.